# How to use cvblob with OpenCV? (already compiled)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, cvblobslib

I finally managed to cmake and compile the cvblob projekt. I thought that it will give me a lib but instead I got a dll. I have the header file and a dll. How can I use them in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. avoid cvblob, it's outdated. it was great 5 years ago, but opencv in general has moved on to c++, and its current api can handle all of it without cvblob (which is using the deprecated c-api.)
2. if you succeeded to compile it, there should have been at least a 'stub' lib  to link to ( which will link your exe to the dll at runtime ). look again.

Comment: What can I use instead of cvblob?

Comment: [findcontours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) , [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments) , [simpleblobdetector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#simpleblobdetector)